# HTML/Javascript disabled and then reenabled checkbox is being POSTED

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with a checkbox that is disabled/reenabled with javascript on button click. If I never disable the checkbox then its value is correctly POSTed, however if I disable the checkbox even once it gets posted without value (posts as "name=" even when checked). I have inspected the POST value through firebug.

Why does it behaves like this? Am I missing something? I ve read somewhere that disabled controls are not posted, thats OK, but this control is not disabled when the submit is clicked.

I am using ASP.NET with more complex setup to test this, but essentially this is the core of the problem. The brower is FF latest.

I found very similar question, however without an answer:
[disabled control being reenabled but still not posting back contents to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856218/disabled-control-being-reenabled-but-still-not-posting-back-contents-to-server)

Comment: Can I see your aspx markup too.

Comment: It is indeed true that disabled form elements are not posted. But if you've re-enabled it before the form is submitted, it should definitely get posted (**if** it's checked; if it's not checked, *nothing* is posted for the checkbox). And it does, for me, on FF latest: http://jsbin.com/oribej/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be in my interpretation of submitted data. As TJ correctly pointed out (it lead me to the solution so thank you!) if the checkbox is not checked then NOTHING is submitted rather than "cbName=" as happened in my case.

The real problem (the reason why I raised this question) was that ASP.NET did not recognize the checked checkbox for postback. But this was however due to yet different reason: my javascript disable function also did this.value = ''. However if you do this to a asp:checkbox then its value (status) is not recognized for postback and the checkbox always appears as not checked on the server. ASP.NET must have cbName=on to recognize checked status for postback.

Well at least I have learned something today. Hopefully this might also help someone else in the future.

Comment: Ah, OK, my answer is probably irrelevant then.  I'll leave it there in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you disabling and re-enabling the checkbox?  The [`disabled` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls%3a-the-disabled-attribute) is a [boolean attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute).  The presence, not the value, of the attribute means it is disabled.  All of these checkboxes are disabled:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cheese" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" name="cheese" disabled="disabled">
<input type="checkbox" name="cheese" disabled="">
<input type="checkbox" name="cheese" disabled="true">
<input type="checkbox" name="cheese" disabled="false">
```

Comment: Thanks, its a valid point, however I believe I did enable/disable the checkbox correctly using JS this.disabled=true or false.